# How to get all records from class with a collection using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

how can I get a new list of object using lambda  from the below scenario:

Example class:
AllCARS is a collection:
    public class AllCars
    {
        int id {get; set;}
        List cars {get; set;}
    }

```
public class cars 
{
   string color;
   string model;
}
```

I tried the following which didn't produce all rows:

```
var carRepo = new AllCars{};

var carsWithIds = carRepo.select(a => new {a.id, a.cars.color, a.cars.model})
```

Here is an example of my tables:

```
AllCars = id:123

cars[] 
color model
red   honda
blue  toyota
```

How can i write the lambda function to produce a list like this
123 red   honda
123 blue  toyota

Comment: `I tried the following which didn't produce all rows:` What's the output ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you cannot perform a linq request to an object with collection. However, you can query the collection inside this object to produce the required output. Hope the following code snippet would help:

```
var carsWithIds = carRepo.cars.Select(a => new {id = carRepo.id, a.color, a.model });
```

This code allows you to get a new object of anonymous class, that contains fields: id, color and model.

There is a little inaccuracy in your code example. Do not forget to make properties of AllCars and cars classes public; otherwise they won't be accessible.

Comment: One thing I should have pointed out that Allcars is a list ....  for each record in all cars I am tring to ouput all cars

Comment: @user1526912 If that's the question you wish you had asked, you should have at least hinted at it. Anyway if you want that (a cross join, right?), try `SelectMany`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that cars have an id property which i wish to match on allcars

Answer (score 0):

Let `AllCarsList` be the collection of `AllCars` then you can make use of extension method `.SelectMany` to get the resultCollection. Please go through the following lines of code and the example and please let me know if it helps as well as for more clarifications.

```
 var resltCollection =  AllCarsList.SelectMany(p => p.cars,(parent, child) => new
                                                  {
                                                      ID = parent.id,
                                                      Color = child.color,
                                                      Model = child.model
                                                  }).ToList();
```

Here is a working [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hn2Idv)

Comment: I should have mentioned that cars have an id property which i wish to match on allcars

Comment: Sorry I don't find any `ID` in the definition of the class that you provided, Please provide the updated class.